# Javascript disable button event completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I would like to know if its possible to do something similar to the example shown below.

```
// Script A
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
   if (not valid) {
       $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
});

// Script B
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
    // Do something else here
});
```

I would like to know whether you can actually stop the click event in ***Script B*** if not valid in ***Script A***. The reason for the two events being separate is due to the fact that ***Script A*** will be used as a sort of a plugin module which will be inserted at the header of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call `$(this).stopPropagation();` and then check for `event.isPropagationStopped()` in Script B.

read more @ http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

use `unbind`. It will not fire the event again unless you `bind` it again

Comment: that seems really inefficient as he'd have to be binding and unbinding a lot afaik.

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you?

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: no, that just prevents the browser from carrying out the normal actions, like an `<a>` tag from going to a site, or a submit from submitting the form.